# android widget that download and prints bitmaps don't work

Tags: java, android

I need to create a widget that will download on the sdcard some bitmaps every minute and will print them on the screen. i have tried to do with

```
private class MyTime extends TimerTask
```

but is don't work. the widget don't update:(
the images have 30K in total. can you help me with this i need only a sample of the code and where i can put my code for the widget to work.
this is the code:

```
public class MyWidget extends AppWidgetProvider {
public int tt=0;

@Override
public void onUpdate( Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds ) {
    if(tt==0) {
        Timer timer = new Timer();
        timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new MyTime(context, appWidgetManager), 1, 10000);
        tt=1;
    }
}

private class MyTime extends TimerTask {

    RemoteViews remoteViews;
    AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager;
    long t=0,lastUpdate=0;
    ComponentName thisWidget;

    public MyTime(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager) {

        this.appWidgetManager = appWidgetManager;
        remoteViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.main);
        thisWidget = new ComponentName(context, MyWidget.class);
    }
    @Override
    public void run() {

        DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM HH:mm");
       //get current date time with Date()
       Date date = new Date();
    remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.Clock,dateFormat.format(date));
    appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(thisWidget, remoteViews);

        if(t==0 || t + 100000<=System.currentTimeMillis()) {
             checkUpdate();
             display();
             t=System.currentTimeMillis();
        }
    }
```

Comment: `don't update` means, there is no UI change or it fails with error, or what?

Comment: it remains withe the initial xml in main.xml

Comment: and you're sure that your code runs, and it should change the UI state?

Comment: yes, and the  remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.Clock,dateFormat.format(date));
    appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(thisWidget, remoteViews);

Answer (score 0):

This is probably failing because a TimerTask runs in its own thread, but you aren’t allowed to make Android UI library calls from any thread other than the UI (main) thread.

To run timed actions on the UI thread, allocate yourself a [Handler](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html) and use its `postDelayed`/`postAtTime` calls.